# Ruby mixins -- getting & setting base class' class variables

Tags: ruby, mixins

What's the best way of setting class variables in a base class? Consider the following code snippet, which is defining a `CacheMixin` to be used with ActiveRecord models. For each model, I want to be able to define the table which is storing the cached data. Is there a better way to do this without using `class_variable_set` and `class_variable_get` ?

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_support/concern'

module CacheMixin
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    module ClassMethods
        def with_cache_table(table)
            self.class_variable_set('@@cache_table', table)
        end
    end

    def fetch_data
        puts self.class.class_variable_get('@@cache_table')
    end

end

class TestClass
    include CacheMixin
    with_cache_table("my_cache_table")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Rails, I'd recommend checking out the [`class_attribute`](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/Class/class_attribute) method.

If you want to do it without Rails, I'd suggest setting an instance variable directly on the class object rather than using class variables (which are generally considered to be bad news).

```
class Foo
  class << self
    attr_accessor :bar
  end
end

Foo.bar = 'hi'
p Foo.bar
#=> 'hi'
```